# Can't reach the variable

Tags: reactjs, variables, use-effect, use-state

I've tried to pass the value of the variable *userId* into my variable *url* in *getRecipeLiked* function but the value is undefined. Even though, when I console log *userId* I do get a value.

```
const  AllRecipes = (props) => {
 
   
    const [decodedToken, setDecodedToken] = useState({})

    // store user's id from decoded token
    const userId = decodedToken.id
    console.log(userId); // output: 14
    
    useEffect(() => {

       const getUserId = () => {
            // 1.retrieve the token from localStorage
            const tokenFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(tokenFromStorage) {            
                // 2. retrieve the payload's token
                const base64Payload = tokenFromStorage.split('.')[1]
                // 3. decoded payload's token and parse it so that we can get the user id
                 setDecodedToken(JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Payload)))
                 console.log(JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Payload)));          
            } else {
                return 'not token to parse'
            }
        }
        getUserId()

        const getRecipeLiked = async () => {
            console.log(userId) //output: undefined
            const url = `http:localhost:4000/user/recipeLiked/${userId}`
            console.log(url); // output: http://localhost:4000/user/recipeLiked/undefined
            
            const result = await axios.get(url)
            setrecipeLiked(result.data)
        }
        getRecipeLiked()

     
    }, [response])
```

Comment: You are not showing where you are setting the decodedToken so perhaps it's a race condition between where you set the token and your useEffect. Try adding `userId ` as your useEffect dependecy and only call `getRecipeLiked` when `userId` is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is happenig is the 'useEffect' is getting trigger before the value is set. Maybe the way you're using its like a componentDidMount().

Comment: I get  and set the value of userId from the same useEffect with _getUserid_ function and then _getRecipeLiked_ function is called

Answer (score 0):

Since `useState` is asynchronous, there is no guarantee that you will have the value you set by `setDecodedToken` in your `getRecipeLiked`. You could change the useEffect to run again when you have the userId value and make the `getRecipeLiked` call only when it's available.

```
    const [decodedToken, setDecodedToken] = useState({})

    // store user's id from decoded token
    const userId = decodedToken.id
    console.log(userId); // output: 14
    
    useEffect(() => {

       const getUserId = () => {
            // 1.retrieve the token from localStorage
            const tokenFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(tokenFromStorage) {            
                // 2. retrieve the payload's token
                const base64Payload = tokenFromStorage.split('.')[1]
                // 3. decoded payload's token and parse it so that we can get the user id
                 setDecodedToken(JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Payload)))
                 console.log(JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Payload)));          
            } else {
                return 'not token to parse'
            }
        }
        // first time through
        if(!userId) getUserId()

        const getRecipeLiked = async () => {
            console.log(userId) //output: undefined
            const url = `http://localhost:4000/user/recipeLiked/${userId}`
            console.log(url); // output: http://localhost:4000/user/recipeLiked/undefined
            
            const result = await axios.get(url)
            setrecipeLiked(result.data)
        }
        // when setState is finished and you have `userId` available. 
        if(userId) getRecipeLiked()

     
    }, [response, userId]) //userId is passed as a dependency so useEffect is run when it changes
```

Comment: It's still not working. But thanks anyway. I'll keep searching a solution